# get value from Dictionary in a tableView with an indexPath.row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, plist

I'm trying to get info from a plist. Here's the struct :

```
Root
-Dictionary
--Dictionary
---String
---String
--Dictionary
---String
---String
--Dictionary
---String
---String
```

edit : And a little sample of it :

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>introduction</key>
    <dict>
        <key>gfx</key>
        <dict>
            <key>titre</key>
            <string>Introduction</string>
            <key>color</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>miniLogo</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>bigLogo</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
...
```

So basically I'm to get the string value from a dictionary nested in another dictionary.

The trick is, I want to use a tableView

So far I'm here :

```
let pathRoot = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyPLIST", ofType: "plist")

let rootRubrique = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pathRoot!)
```

I'm trying to get the info like that :

```
let rubriqueTitre = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pathRoot!)?.allKeys[indexPath.row].objectForKey("gfx")?.valueForKey("titre")
```

But maybe the problem is from the way I'm trying to screen that

```
label.text = imageRubrique! as! String
// And also tried :
label.text = "\(imageRubrique!)"
```

Also I tried to get other values, just to try. This is working for me :

```
let rubriqueIndex = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pathRoot!)?.allKeys[indexPath.row]
 label.text = rubriqueIndex as! String
```

I get the "introduction" with a lower case, the first one. But I don't want that value, I want the nested one ! I'm getting crazy! Fortunately for me Stackoverflow exist!

After that, I'll have to find a way to sort my dictionary in the right order which seems to be another big problem…

edit : I solved the first issue like that. I've created this func :

```
func getValueFromPLIST(rub: String, sousDossier : String, sousSousDossier : String?, value : String) -> String {

if sousSousDossier == nil {

    return (NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pathRoot!)!.objectForKey(rub)!.objectForKey(sousDossier)!.valueForKey(value) as? String)!
} else {

    return (NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pathRoot!)!.objectForKey(rub)!.objectForKey(sousDossier)!.objectForKey((sousSousDossier!))!.valueForKey(value) as? String)!
}

}
```

then I'm assigning the index to a constant :

```
let rubriqueIndex = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pathRoot!)?.allKeys[indexPath.row]
```

And then I'm generating the whole valueForKey via the func :

```
let rubriquePathTitre = getValueFromPLIST(String(rubriqueIndex!), sousDossier: "gfx", sousSousDossier: nil, value: "titre")
```

I have no idea why it's working with that trick, but it's working, and it's not so bad since I need the index somewhere else. But unfortunately I think I'm gonna have to use something else, like a "rank" or "ID" value to sort my dictionary. So the whole thing is useless in the end haha!

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting errors?

Comment: Yeah I'm getting the SIGABRT one !

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: Where do you get eh SIGABRT?

Comment: Well in front of class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {… The error is too big in the console to be copy/paste here ! Should it work ? My code?

Comment: Set an all-exceptions breakpoint. Where are you crashing?

Comment: Also, "sorting" a dictionary does not make sense because dictionaries do not have any notion of ordering. They are simply key-value pairs.

Comment: I'd suggest you to post a sample content of the plist file. That will help us to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Ok here's a little bit of my plist !

Comment: Post the first lines (like 5/10 should be enough) of the crashlogs of your console.

Comment: To `iterate` through all the elements of plist, your root element should be `Array` then you can access objects using index. Here in your case its `Dictionary`, so its not possible to do so, make your root element as Array it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UITableView` index instead iteration index

```
// *** Access data from plist ***
let pathRoot = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyPLIST", ofType: "plist")

// *** Get Root element of plist ***
let rootRubrique = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pathRoot!)

// *** get Next element which is `Introduction` holding all other objects ***
let objIntro:NSDictionary = rootRubrique!.objectForKey("introduction") as! NSDictionary
```

**Option 1 : Iterate Through all objects using Index**

```
for var i = 1; i <= objIntro.allValues.count; ++i
{
    print("Index[\(i)] \(objIntro.allValues[0])")
}
```

**Access Using indexpath in your case**

```
let obj = (objIntro.allValues[indexPath.row])
```

**Option 2 : Iterate through allValues of dictionary**

```
for (key, value) in objIntro
{
    print("key: \"\(key as! String)\" obj : \(value)")
}
```

Comment: I think I'm going to use a for loop with some kind of "rank" value at some point to sort them ! I'll try that tonight. Thanks everybody, it's a great community!